# Is there a collection of short stories for "Writing Fiction" by Janet Burroway

Tags: book-rec

"Writing Fiction" by Janet Burroway gives numerous short story examples and "Suggested Stories" to read.

Is there a book that collects all of these short stories together?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps your local Library…?

Comment: @EDL:  The pictured book suggests reading certain short stories.  It doesn't contain thosse short stories.  It is a book on writing techniques that gives some examples that use those techniques.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found a simple solution that will get me 85% of the way there. They removed the short stories in the 10th edition. I can get (most) of them by buying the 9th edition used.